# How to write a list of integers to a file as 16 bit values in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have a list of integers with values between [0-65535].
I need to write these to a file as 16 bit integers.

How do I do this in Elixir?

I have searched, but I am confused about ints and binaries and how to perform the conversion for 16 bit values.

I have found how to convert to a 16 bit binary:

```
<<12345 :: size(16)>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can alternatively use streams:

```
[1, 2, 3]
|> Stream.map(&<<&1::16>>)
|> Enum.into(File.stream!(filename))
```

This uses the short form `::16` instead of `::size(16)`. The file stream will take care of opening and closing the file automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

```
{:ok, file} = File.open(filename, [:write])

[1, 2, 3] |> Enum.each(fn(x) -> IO.binwrite(file, <<x :: size(16)>>) end)

File.close(file)
```